# How to Join table with specific fields when using sequelize on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to execute a query through sequelize. I have 4 tables: **userInfo** (which contains a foreign key ("group_id")), **group_user** (which contains information about the user group), **privilege** (which contains information about privileges) and finaly a join table **group_privileges** (which has 2 foreign keys on tables group_user and privilege)

**MODEL DEFINITION**

Model defined in userInfo.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('userInfo', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    group_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: '1',
      references: {
        model: 'group_user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'userInfo',
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  });
};
```

Model defined in group_privilege.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('group_privilege', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    group_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'group_user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    privilege_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'privilege',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'group_privilege',
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  });
};
```

Model defined in group_user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('group_user', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'group_user',
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  });
};
```

Model defined in privilege.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('privilege', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 'N/D'
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'privilege',
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  });
};
```

**Here is the code I am executing to make my query**:

```
var privilege = Mysequelize.import(path.join(process.cwd() + "/models/privilege.js"));
var group_privilege = Mysequelize.import(path.join(process.cwd() + "/models/group_privilege.js"));
var userInfo = Mysequelize.import(path.join(process.cwd() + "/models/userInfo.js"));
var group_user = Mysequelize.import(path.join(process.cwd() + "/models/group_user.js"));

group_privilege.belongsTo(privilege, {foreignKey:'privilege_id', targetKey:"id"});
privilege.hasMany(group_privilege, {foreignKey:'privilege_id', targetKey:"id"});

userInfo.belongsTo(group_privilege, {foreignKey:'group_id', targetKey:'group_id'});
group_privilege.hasOne(userInfo, {foreignKey:'group_id', targetKey:'group_id'});                

Mysequelize.sync().then(function(){            
   privilege.findAll({include:[{model:group_privilege, include:{model:userInfo, where: id:req.user.id}}}]}).then(function(final_priv){
     var list_of_privileges = [];
     for (var key in final_priv){
        list_of_privileges.push(final_priv[key].dataValues.id);
     }
     res.type('application/json').status(200).send({"userPrivileges":list_of_privileges});                
        }).catch(function(err){
          return next(err)});
    }).catch(function(err){
      var errMsg = "Error while getting user privileges in database: " + err; 
      console.log(errMsg);
       res.status(500).send(errMsg);
    });
}).catch(function(err){
  return next('Unable to connect to the database:' + err);
});
```

**What I expect to happen?**

The ideal output query would be this:

```
SELECT "privilege"."id", 
       "privilege"."description", 
       "privilege"."code"
FROM "privilege" AS "privilege" 
INNER JOIN "group_privilege" AS "group_privileges" ON "privilege"."id" = "group_privileges"."privilege_id" 
INNER JOIN "userInfo" AS "group_privileges.userInfos" ON "group_privileges"."group_id" = "group_privileges.userInfos"."group_id"
WHERE "group_privileges.userInfos".id = 15;
```

> Note that in the WHERE condition, the number 15 is just a dynamic id
>   number. We don't need to focus on this value.

**What is actually happening?**

When enabling the logging option, we can see that executed SQL query is:

```
SELECT "privilege"."id", 
    "privilege"."description", 
    "privilege"."code", 
    "group_privileges"."id" AS "group_privileges.id", 
    "group_privileges"."group_id" AS "group_privileges.group_id", 
    "group_privileges"."privilege_id" AS "group_privileges.privilege_id", 
    "group_privileges.userInfos"."username" AS "group_privileges.userInfos.username", 
    "group_privileges.userInfos"."id" AS "group_privileges.userInfos.id", 
    "group_privileges.userInfos"."group_id" AS "group_privileges.userInfos.group_id" 
FROM "privilege" AS "privilege" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "group_privilege" AS "group_privileges" ON "privilege"."id" = "group_privileges"."privilege_id" 
INNER JOIN "userInfo" AS "group_privileges.userInfos" ON "group_privileges"."id" = "group_privileges.userInfos"."group_id" AND "group_privileges.userInfos"."id" = 15;
```

My issue here is the last join. Instead of having :

```
INNER JOIN "userInfo" AS "group_privileges.userInfos" ON "group_privileges"."group_id" = "group_privileges.userInfos"."group_id" AND "group_privileges.userInfos"."id" = 15;
```

I have

```
INNER JOIN "userInfo" AS "group_privileges.userInfos" ON "group_privileges"."id" = "group_privileges.userInfos"."group_id" AND "group_privileges.userInfos"."id" = 15;
```

> (... The issue here is: ...ON "group_privileges"."**id**" ... instead of
>   ...ON "group_privileges"."**group_id**")

As you can see, I'm trying to force the join condition on specific fields of group_privileges.userInfos and group_privileges. But for a reason I can't figure out, it takes the "**id**" field of the group_privileges table instead to take the "**group_id**" field of this table.

Does anyone can tell me please what I am doing wrong or if there is an issue/bug from sequelize module ? If I am doing something wrong, can you tell me what exactly and what would be the solution ?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Dialect: postgres

Database version: 9.4.4

Sequelize version: 3.23.0